# This result of nonexistence of Hamilton–Jacobi equations in Lebesgue spaces is valid in domains?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

In the article [The local theory for viscous Hamilton–Jacobi equations in Lebesgue spaces](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271968/1-s2.0-S0021782400X00517/1-s2.0-S0021782401012430/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEM%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDfH01H6H%2FsOo%2F1T8v7j4hGWgmMHNUtaKXvcGG7jBcOlwIhANm0OR%2BkatNRC%2Fjc%2BYTNUEUU1muT8AexJ9HGjfNWA4gxKrsFCPf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1Igx3zRjjePvmXvNfG%2FMqjwVVTJGgdTgNHQjaSTR0lhvYak1BFKBHliCo0Z%2BjJtUMVLSimp5XUaU%2FKz%2BcQxyaRAK8fKhhdQXexAs7hAxDrsNekIXb1rP5LPj%2BILZTH34p1%2BhfXKeysg2mcessCdvKavwQTNZDR%2BHc4Mm7%2FqK51bC16NaPVYP3UGa0uH0M2FYBBXoTUq1FKbFsrA3HGkl%2BoKownUle%2BZoPasrSaMR3etqhNsr5oWTZN9P%2FuU6DO5XEa2r9ThII5zdRCR4XdGIpwPrYcbW2TmJcOJFGVumnSuzMqsEcd639mSDAYyceVxGruBCgo2Yxy%2BaXAXxGCL7e2W9r1iyMP2TtR2DnUgWxg4J1vR88J7RuyDH6BaZRis%2Bwhyl98QIps3DLqv%2B3GlffrLxWNvn7V39xd%2BdxBiECVqBcZ5O92QEsh0vqQ7fOYbPRqNx8%2B7FM%2BGSN7p3VvaxBshDPSE6LfWHrbg1LemzGrEQfgcn8gQex1SxUT%2FnioXmghJPuTe9jMi%2F3hzd9tYjCkiDsa55YSTv7wXxyvHC9L4z8ScnmckG0wZwUFPKpj2K%2BeX80bPvS9YgUMdZCpMNeSRV1TXgKw1D3HsqKH19BBsQ%2BDmi%2BBIhAvUfFesS3MxKKEbyGbRkswjgLbjj3OmWqhJZLLSiBGernmbyKclrxB7Hq6nts6gM1zfyGJXi4pi0RSag3sO8XYv%2FyW8R3mJUWji4lvtiF6XDTrtZ7RAnVa8YYPH9LVLx5e1ZVlHVHfruz2Uuf2gc7tapgW%2FH4XZUEO4wDX0K962Y%2BgsRP%2BLgtmJsGmu%2BdQEjeqsaZ6Y0XI%2B1rqmVrA6pppU4LweFkpTTcYAKfi%2B%2FdrrFhVFodUx3gHavHfcWpBLcJ6cTQ5DQa5WbMMImbuqMGOrABSgISsGg6RKTMqyxrBJWf7JU07N%2FEmysajjytR6RP9DJMSQB0pm5IvrEgp9o1issNyqjqnxuMn9TU4Fgd197v6fcVXIQihOlxZFs93Zs%2FML%2B9jlh9XrEO10x1rrcsxbvj4d5Mtd7J%2FsC%2FDLstxpjgWK%2FLzR90eaPQvw2n%2Fa6jiE0ZRNUtDpVepFThBhvlhScccJoQXfs59AEsUyoryBn96vABVef9IfBkPQBl2y53dYA%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230524T230817Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY5QLDPYNJ%2F20230524%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=b50bedb564188b2c647d36500bf72d9e0464ee5c42c39aed8462a57e755cea9e&hash=0fbc0136a3b037e545d0196b4514219382cd7979ac162e7b0fc6bdd3544381b1&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021782401012430&tid=spdf-1bcfcaa8-40f0-4b8e-8336-33ebe1941451&sid=bd733d964b4e92431228e90-ddd2e98b883egxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=041459050d5a575c5153&rr=7cc93320586b00c3&cc=br) Ben Artzi, Souplet, Weisller studies the equation
\begin{equation}
        \left\{ 
        \begin{array}{rll}
            u_t -  \Delta u &=  |\nabla u|^{p}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T), \\   
            {u}(0) &=  {u}_{0}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n, \\
        \end{array}
        \right.
    \end{equation}

and shows the global existence of a classical solution in suitable $L^{q}$ spaces for $1<p<2$. If $p\geq 2$ the local existence of classical solutions fails in all $L^{q}$ spaces ($q < \infty$). He shows this in proposition 3.1 (page 362):
[image]

I have 3 questions about this proposition. First, as for the argument which I'm not sure I understand correctly, he seems to be doing it by contradiction, when he assumes that $u_0 \in L^1_{loc}$ and gets $\exp(u_0) \in L^1_{loc}$. Another thing, how does he know that $G_{R+1}(0,y,t_0-\varepsilon) \geq C(t_0,R)$? Because there is the Heat Kernel on the ball, I don't know such an estimate for domains smaller than $\mathbb{R}^n$, if this estimate is true, it is true for other domains, such as cones, rings, cubes...? I am asking these questions, because this being true, perhaps he could make an even stronger result, in which he would show that non-existence holds in any unbounded domain.

Comment: It is not nice to type the name of one of the article's authors wrong, and omit the other two. // It is not a proof by contradiction, since $u_0\in L^1_{loc}$ does not contradict $\exp(a u_0)\in L^1_{loc}$. The idea is that $\exp(a u_0)\in L^1_{loc}$ means that $u_0$ cannot be a generic element of $L^q$. The proposition says that "the only way that an $L^q$ initial data generates a classical solution is that the initial data is not a generic $L^q$ element"; hence its contrapositive says "generic $L^q$ elements do not generate classical solutions".